# upload file with aioftp client

Tags: python, async-await, ftp, python-asyncio

sorry my english is not good but i have a question with aioftp client.
I try to send a file from my server to another server using ftp.
Here is my code:

```
async with aioftp.ClientSession(host, FTP_PORT, login, password) as ftp: 

     async with ftp.path_io.open(file_path, mode="rb") as file_in, ftp.upload_stream(new_file_name) as stream: 
          async for block in file_in.iter_by_block(8192):  
               await stream.write(block)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKiST.png)

It logs in successfully and then immediately exits:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYMFZ.png)

Then I tried using the ftplib library:

```
with FTP(host) as ftp: 
      ftp.login(user,password) with open(file_path, "rb") as f: 
          ftp.storbinary('STOR '+new_file_name, f)
```

[image: Python code]

It works fine but not asynchronously. Please help me, I need to send the file with asynchronous method.

**Debug with wireshark:**

*aiofpt:*

[image: Wireshark Screenshot 1]

ftplib:

[image: Wireshark Screenshot 2]

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `async` in Python, but I guess that the `with` exits immediately, because of `async` before `for`, taking the FTP session down with it. Do not use `with` for the session, if you want to keep it opened for the async tasks.

Comment: Your code appears garbled, newline and indentation is lost. Please fix the formatting.